# WebView - страница не загрузилась

Tags: java, android, webview

Есть готовое webview, созданное в Android Studio. Приложение настроено и работает. При слабом сигнале интернет соединения, либо при отсутствии интернета в приложении появляется запись об ошибке:
"The webpage at https://suit.ru could not be loaded because:
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_resolved"
Для работоспособности приложения, необходимо перезапустить приложение и заново загрузить страницу в мобильном браузере.
Нужна Ваша помощь в изменении имеющегося кода webview,  чтобы при слабом сигнале интернет соединения, либо отсутствии сигнала, появлялась локально размещенная страница из приложения, на которой написано "Слабый сигнал интернета" и кнопка, при нажатии на которую будет инициирована попытка обновить страницу.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой код - куда нужно вписать, на основе имеющегося кода и в какой последовательности?

```
Активити
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    Мэйн
package com.work.rabotayou;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://ewwo.ru/work.php");

        WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N) @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return true;
            }
        };
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                        mWebView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}

    Манифест
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.work.rabotayou">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте может отвечаю слишком поздно, но лучше поздно чем никогда. Итак чтобы при какой либо ошибке делать код в вашем WebView вам нужно в вашем WebViewClient перезаписать метод `onReceivedError`. Чтобы отобразить свою собственную страницу с ошибкой вы должны создать папку (там где папка java, res и AndroidManifest.xml) assets и там поместить ваш html с ошибкой. Затем в переопределённом методе написать `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")` Пример:

```
WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }
    });
}
```

Если что-то не понятно задавайте вопросы также дополнительную информацию вы можете найти [здесь](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted/)

Также в качестве альтернативы могу предложить такой вариант т. к. в 1 способе в нём есть недостатки метод как положено срабатывает только при первом запуске и если во время работы WebView было перенаправление то не загружалась страница с ошибкой даже если бы загрузилась то на секунду была бы страница с стандартной ошибкой. В данном способе я сделал немного хитро я использовал два WebView. Первый для работы с онлайн страницой второй для оффлайн страницы (с ошибкой). Итак в макете нужно поместить второй WebView и задать ему `android:visibility="gone"` в коде Java нужно при вызове ошибки скрывать онлайн WebView который используется для онлайна и показывать второй WebView который используется для ошибки вот код:

```
WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("https://suit.ru/");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            WebView secondWebView = findViewById(R.id.secondWebView);
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            secondWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            secondWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");;
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Вызов `super.onReceivedError(...)` здесь не лишний? Я подозреваю что он обработает ошибку и перекроет нашу страничку дефолтной.

Comment: Хм я был не сильно понял о чём вы имели в ввиду, но когда я пытался поработать с моим способом выяснил несколько проблем и так я обновил свой ответ и добавил второй альтернативный вариант надеюсь этот вариант вам поможет.